# How to retrieve all Record Ids of a Sub Grid in CRM 2011 using javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a subgrid named `TimeTickets`, I try:

```js
var gridControl = document.getElementById('TimeTickets_d').control;
var ids = gridControl.get_allRecordIds();
```

but I get the following error:

> Object doesn't support  property or method 'get_allRecordIds'

Notes:

- CRM Rollup Update 13
- Browser: Internet Explorer 9

Comment: because this code is unsupported, you need to provide more information such as rollup version and browser used.

Comment: I apologize for not having written before,I use Rollup  13 and IE9

Comment: What action requires you to get them (ribbon button, change event, custom page button, etc.)?

Comment: this triggered the onload event

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

```js
var grid = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('TimeTickets')._control;

if (grid.get_innerControl() == null) {
    setTimeout(subGridOnload, 1000);
    return;
}
else if (grid.get_innerControl()._element.innerText.search("Loading") != -1) {
    setTimeout(subGridOnload, 1000);
    return;
}

var ids = grid.get_innerControl().get_allRecordIds();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states the method get_allRecordIds is not supported for that particular control. I would guess that Microsoft MAY have changed the structure of the HTML meaning that its not looking at the correct control.

I'd suggest you use this instead

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('TimeTickets')._control.get_innerControl().get_allRecordIds();
```

EDIT
As mentioned by anykey3 this solution doesn't appear to work all the time either. I have it working on CRM Online however CRM on premise doesn't seem to work correctly.  One solution I have that works is using the RESTful service which might not be the best solution as it requires ALOT more code.

```
    function GetChildrenValues()
    {
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId() != null)
    {
        var odataFieldName = "ContactSet";
        var identifier = new Array();
        identifier[0] = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

        var context = Xrm.Page.context;
        var serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();
        var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";

        var odataUri = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName + '?$filter=accountid eq {GUID}';


        odataUri +=  '?$filter=accountid eq {GUID}';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: odataUri,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.             
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                SuccessCallback(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest);
            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Handle Error
            }
        });
    }
}

function SuccessCallback(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest)
{
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var total = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me... when I call get_innerControl() method it returns null. and there is no method named get_allRecordIds()

Answer (score 0):

check this code its working fine in dynamics crm 2013

```
function RetrieveSubGridRecords() {
debugger;
    if (document.getElementById("Contacts")) {
        var grid = document.getElementById("Contacts").control;
        for (var rowNo = 0; rowNo < grid.GetRecordsFromInnerGrid().length; rowNo++)
            for (var cellNo = 0; cellNo < grid.GetRecordsFromInnerGrid()[rowNo][3].cells.length; cellNo++)
                alert(grid.GetRecordsFromInnerGrid()[rowNo][3].cells[cellNo].outerText);    }    else {
        setTimeout("RetrieveSubGridRecords();", 2500);
    }}
```